# In Javascript, why can't we set prototypal inheritance arbitrarily?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

With Crockford's definition:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

and ECMA-262's introduction of `Object.create()`, we now can set a new object `a`'s hidden prototype property to point to another object `b` for pure prototypal inheritance.  But it is limited to a new object, and Javascript still won't allow something like

```
a.__proto__ = b;
```

for an existing object `a` in the ECMA-262 Javascript specification.  Is there a reason to limit it to a new object but not for existing objects?

Comment: _"Plus, I had to be done in ten days or something worse than JS would have happened"_ -- Brendan Eich, creator of JavaScript. Which is to say that some parts of JavaScript are a little strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MDN `__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) entry, ES6 will allow assigning to an object's `[[Prototype]]`. The article previously (since October 2010) said that the property was deprecated. It will likely be some years yet before that is useful on the web, particularly as it's very difficult to implement robustly in browsers that don't support it.

I expect that the `__proto__` property will be read–only for built–in objects and for host objects that have it.

You'll have to ask Brendan Eich why the `[[Prototype]]` property was hidden and could only be set through a constructor, but I suspect that he wanted to keep JavaScript simple and not allow the kind of abuse handed out to `eval`.

As for Crockford's `beget`, it was first published as `clone` by [Lasse Reichstein Nielsen](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/5d06e72e55d5bf11) as a way to clone objects and has since been replaced by ES5 [Object.create](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5).

Answer (score 1):

One reason I can see is to avoid the possibility of circular references.

Comment: FF/Chrome just throw an error when you try to set up a *`cyclic __proto__ value`*. Yet, they allow normal assignments